# Question on importing two classes with the same name - android.graphics.Color

Tags: android

I currently have a imported color class from another Android Library:

`import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Color;`

but I need to import another color class:

`import android.graphics.Color;`

but after typing this import, it gives me the error:

[image]

so I have to end up removing the second import and use it manually like this:

`mBtnColor.setColorFilter(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(color));`

is there a way I can import both classes? or maybe use the second import without typing `android.graphics.Color`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two classes: one inherits the first Color and does nothing and is called AndroidGraphicsColor and the other one inherits the appropriate class and is called AndroidSceneFormRenderingColor. Then use them.